# Expand $\frac{e^{5z}}{(z-5)^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Expand $\frac{e^{5z}}{(z-5)^3}$ around $z=5$

$$\frac{e^{5z}}{(z-5)^3}=\frac{e^{5z-25+25}}{(z-5)^3}=\frac{e^{25}e^{5(z-5)}}{(z-5)^3}=\frac{e^{25}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5^n}{n!}(z-5)^n}{(z-5)^3}={e^{25}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5^n}{n!}(z-5)^{n-3}}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: @Bernard I have fixed it

Comment: Looks good to me, but you might wish to change the index of summation in the final sum so that it becomes $\sum_{n=-3}^\infty (5^n/(n+3)!)(z-5)^n$. This fits better with the usual conventions for presenting a Laurent series.